# Button can't be clicked with relative div

Tags: html, css, web

I`m trying to make a button clickable, but with no lucky, already tried z-index and absolute positions on it, but the father div has a "position:relative" that screw up everything.. and I can't take it, since it makes the parallax effect on my page

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/J4HN8/

```
#separatorMJ3{
     position: relative;
     color:#fff;        
     background-image: url("http://stuffkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Guitar-HD-Wallpaper-5.jpg");
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     z-index:-1;
     width: 100%;
     padding-top:80px;
     padding-bottom:80px;
}

<div id="separatorMJ3">
     <a href=#>Check in</a>
</div>
```

What can I do with it?

ps.: the fiddle is with link, but it is the same idea

Comment: Solved! Could you answer and I can mark it with correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `z-index:-1;` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4HN8/1/)

Comment: could you provide some explanation for this? I have a feeling that there is some ***unknown*** layer somewhere and `z-index:-1` will put the whole `div` behind this ***unknown*** layer, that's strange indeed. Although it's obvious that the HTML code does not have any other layer element.

Comment: @KingKing my understanding is when set to `relative` it is relative to the parent (which is `<body>` in this case).  Then the `z-index:-1` puts the div and everything contained in it behind the parent.

Comment: ah looks like I've tested the wrong code, yes actually it's hidden behind the `body` in this case.

Comment: @KingKing The fiddle that you provided is positioning the div as absolute.  If you change it relative you will see it appears behind the body.  [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4HN8/4/)

Comment: Well while trying solving another problem related to `z-index`, I've found out that the ***unknown*** layer I mentioned above is actually the ***html*** element, not the ***body***, here is the updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/J4HN8/5/ (the last demo also adds background for `html`, hence it covers the div).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of this attribute `z-index:-1`

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4HN8/)